# Не работают горячие клавиши при русской раскладке в Android Studio

Tags: ubuntu, ide, android-studio

При английской раскладке грячие клавиши работают без проблем. Но когда переключаю раскладку на русскую, перестают работать. У кого нибудь была такая проблема? Может это баг Android Studio?

Comment: Какая версия ubuntu у вас?

Comment: @AdamLuisSean Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Я не вспомню уже, как найти issue, но это тесно связанная с java проблему, которые джетбрейнсы пока вафлят. В linux mint в виртуалке все ок, а в lubuntu на ноутбуке - нет.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Эта проблема тянется еще с ранних версий Ubuntu. Возможно в дальнейшем поправят.

Answer (score 5):

Как заметил AdamLuisSean, это еще тянется с 
*12.04*

Это проблема *JVM*, поэтому ее не хотят фиксить jetBrains вроде как,
 есть костыль модифицирующий вызовы клавиатуры c кириллицой https://github.com/zheludkovm/LinuxJavaFixes

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).

Comment: пример по-русски: http://whyte624.ru/2014/12/13/linux-java-hotkeys-fix/

Comment: JAVA, и соответственно входящий в него JVM - продукт компании Oracle. JetBrains же - небольшая компания выпускающая серию популярных IDE для нескольких языков программирования.

Answer (score 4):

Мне с такой проблемой в других программах помог `unity-settings-daemon`, см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/469242/185618