# Проблема с быстрыми клавишами в не-английской раскладке в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

На моем Ubuntu 14.04 стоят LibreOffice и [OmegaT](http://www.omegat.org/ru/omegat.html).
Кроме английского, я пишу на русском и иврите.

Проблема в том, что быстрые клавиши в OmegaT работают только в английской раскладке, а в LibreOffice — в английской и русской, но не на иврите.
Что можно с этим сделать?

**Upd:** после перехода на 16.04 проблема вернулась, <s>но прошлое решение не работает. :(</s>
`java-non-latin-shortcuts` починили.

**Upd2:** На 18.04 все работает.

---

аналогичный «баг»: [Не работают горячие клавиши при русской раскладке в Android Studio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428378/178576)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Это известный [баг](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1226962), что горячие клавиши не работают на не-латинских раскладках.
Решение:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:attente/java-non-latin-shortcuts
sudo apt-get update
```

Убедитесь, что проинсталлированы пакеты `gnome-settings-daemon` и `unity-settings-daemon` (последние версии!).
Затем

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
restart unity-settings-daemon
```

<s>**Upd:** работает на 14.04, а на 16.04 — нет.</s>

**Upd2:** Ура, `java-non-latin-shortcuts` починили! Спасибо  Vladislav Rastrusny, что рассказал нам.
Устанавливается 4-мя командами описанными выше. Пакет `gnome-settings-daemon` не нужен.

Comment: Сейчас уже работает на 16.04.3

Comment: На 16.04.3 патч все еще проблемный. Поначалу вроде работает, но через какое-то время перестают работать хоткеи, которые без патча всегда работали в английской раскладке. Например `CTRL+/` (Toggle comment) перестало работать в EN, если жать слэш на основной клавиатуре. Работает только если жать слэш на NumPad-блоке.

Comment: А можно без обновления до 18-й версии добиться работоспособности?

Comment: @Dims, согласно Upd2 пакет java-non-latin-shortcuts работает на 16.04. Устанавливается, как указано в ответе.

Answer (score 4):

> Это известный баг, что горячие клавиши не работают на не-латинских раскладках.
>   Решение:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:attente/java-non-latin-shortcuts
> sudo apt-get update
> ```
>
> Убедитесь, что поинсталлированы пакеты `gnome-settings-daemon` и `unity-settings-daemon` (последние версии!).
>
> Затем
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
> restart unity-settings-daemon
> ```

После этого у меня заработало. Но! На английском отвалилось =) Все наоборот стало! Говорят, что  в 14.04 отлично работал `java-non-latin-shortcuts`, но в 16.04 проблема вернулась. У меня как раз 16.04.

Отменил так:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:attente/java-non-latin-shortcuts
restart unity-settings-daemon
```

Рабочие решения [есть на onedev](http://onedev.net/post/469). Лично я испробовал `ibus-m17n`. Хватило меня на день. Переключение языков с 3-го раза, в sublime3,  valentina studio вообще русский язык не был доступен.

Второе, и на чем я остановился, это `LinuxJavaFixes`. Пока нареканий нет. Самое главное в IDE работает. [Вот инструкция](https://github.com/zheludkovm/LinuxJavaFixes)

Comment: Увы, мне LinuxJavaFixes не помогает. Я не знаю, как заставить LibreOffice бежать с этим файлом, и не знаю, как сделать такой файл для иврита, потому что не пишу на Javе :(

Comment: желательно, чтобы ответ содержал сам ответ, а не только ссылки (ссылки полезны, но за они могут умереть, за них нельзя голосовать, комментировать конкретные детали, поправлять содержимое со временем. Вместо цитаты полного ответа, можно было просто сказать: java-non-latin-shortcuts решение из [@user244413 ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/469242/23044) заработало/отвалилось итд

Comment: На 16.04 сейчас уже должно работать.