# Ubunta не реагирует на комбинацию клавиш Ctrl+C и Ctrl+V

Tags: ubuntu, settings

Каждый раз когда я хочу скопировать и вставить текст, сталкиваюсь с проблемой, что я не могу этого сделать если включена русская раскладка... Когда включаю англ раскладку все работает. Подскажите в чес может быть проблема?

Comment: переключение раскладки, случаем, не поставлено в простое нажатие на CTRL? еще там есть эффектики разные, которые можно на CTRL навесить, типа "подсветить, где мышь нажатием на CTRL"

Comment: это, случайно, происходит не в программе, написанной на java? тогда вопрос дублирует [этот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428378/178576) или [этот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/469241/178576).