# Не работают кейстроки в CLion на русском в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, клавиатура, clion

Большинство комбинаций клавиш типа Ctrl-буква (например, Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V) не работают в CLion когда выбран русский язык. Приходится сперва переключаться на английский, набирать комбинацию, затем переключаться обратно (при необходимости).

Можно ли это как-то вылечить?

OS Ubuntu 16 LTS

Comment: А где это работает, не подскжите?

Comment: жабобаг вульгарис. [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428378/178576) [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/469241/178576)